# Adding Permalink to Slides with 'Simple Nivo Slider' plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, php, slideshow

*Update April 27 10:57 AM -- Fail Log*

To **clarify**, I've only customized and adjusted the CSS.

The first slide works correctly with linking through, but *ONLY* on the first cycle / initial page load. Then the next time it slides through, it stops linking.

***??***

--

**Orginal Q:**

So, I guess out of the box. The ***Simple Nivo*** Slider plugin, (*though it's supposed too?*), doesn't have the permalink enabled to click through on slides to the actual corresponding recent posts.

**So I need to do this manually as I've already customized the slider enough where it would hurt to start all over.**

So, I've used this plugin: **http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/**

Before I'd use the php snippet below; but I'm wondering where I could add it within the plugin files?

```
<?php the_permalink() ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this? AH!?

**--- FULL 'simple-nivo-slider.php' below:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simple Nivo Slider
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/
Description: Gilbert Pellegrom's excellent Nivo Slider, made easily available for WordPress
Version: 0.5.6
Author: Thomas M Steenholdt
Author URI: http://www.tmus.dk/
License: GLP2
*/

/*  Copyright 2011  Thomas Munck Steenholdt  (email : tmus@tmus.dk)

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

/* plugin database version - used to identify the need to "upgrade" database */
define('SNIVO_DB_VERSION', 5);

/* supported effects */
define('SNIVO_EFFECTS', 'fold fade sliceDownRight sliceDownLeft sliceUpRight sliceUpLeft sliceUpDown sliceUpDownLeft slideInRight slideInLeft boxRandom boxRain boxRainReverse boxRainGrow boxRainGrowReverse');


/*
 * define default values for all plugin options
 * the function can return the entire array or the value of a single option if opt_name is specified
 */
function snivo_defaults($opt_name=null) {

    $defaults = Array(
        'snivo_category' => 1,
        'snivo_imagesize' => 'full',
        'snivo_shuffle' => 0,
        'snivo_nivo_effects' => explode(' ', constant('SNIVO_EFFECTS')),
        'snivo_nivo_slices' => 15,
        'snivo_nivo_boxcols' => 8,
        'snivo_nivo_boxrows' => 4,
        'snivo_nivo_animspeed' => 500,
        'snivo_nivo_pausetime' => 3000,
        'snivo_nivo_directionnav' => 1,
        'snivo_nivo_directionnavhide' => 1,
        'snivo_nivo_controlnav' => 1,
        'snivo_nivo_keyboardnav' => 1,
        'snivo_nivo_pauseonhover' => 1,
        'snivo_nivo_captionopacity' => 80
    );

    /* return entire array if $opt_name is empty */
    if (empty($opt_name))
        return $defaults;

    /* otherwise return the value of the specified option from the array */
    return $defaults[$opt_name];

};


/*
 * plugin activation hook
 */
function snivo_activate() {

    /* add/update all plugin options */
    update_option('snivo_db_version', constant('SNIVO_DB_VERSION'));
    foreach (snivo_defaults() as $opt_name => $default_value) {
        add_option($opt_name, $default_value);
    }

}


/*
 * plugin deactivation hook
 */
function snivo_deactivate() {

    /* remove deprecated options from the database on deactivation */ 
    delete_option('snivo_nivo_testtest');

}


/*
 * plugin uninstallation hook
 */
function snivo_uninstall() {

    /* delete all plugin options */
    delete_option('snivo_db_version');
    foreach (snivo_defaults() as $opt_name => $default_value) {
        delete_option($opt_name);
    }

}


/*
 * display an administrative notice when database is updated
 */
function snivo_update_notice() {
    ?>
        <div class="updated fade"><p>
            <strong>Simple Nivo Slider:</strong> database was updated.
        </p></div>
    <?php
}


/*
 * handle plugin updates
 */
function snivo_update_helper() {

    /*
     * if current database 'snivo_db_version' is lower that the plugin database version,
     * update the plugin database by calling the deactivate() and activate() functions
     */
    if (intval(get_option('snivo_db_version')) < constant('SNIVO_DB_VERSION')) {
        /* deactivate, activate will handle addition of new options to the database
         * and update the db_version too */
        snivo_deactivate();
        snivo_activate();

        /* notify administrator of the update */
        add_action('admin_notices', 'snivo_update_notice');
    }

}


/*
 * plugin admin_init action function
 */
function snivo_admin_init() {

    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_category', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_imagesize');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_shuffle', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_effects');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_slices', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_boxcols', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_boxrows', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_animspeed', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_pausetime', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_directionnav', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_directionnavhide', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_controlnav', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_keyboardnav', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_pauseonhover', 'intval');
    register_setting('snivo-settings', 'snivo_nivo_captionopacity', 'intval');

    snivo_update_helper();

}


/*
 * plugin admin_menu action function
 */
function snivo_admin_menu() {

    if (function_exists('add_submenu_page'))
            add_submenu_page('plugins.php','Simple Nivo Slider configuration', 'Simple Nivo Slider', 'manage_options', 'snivo_menu', 'snivo_admin_options');

}


/*
 * this is the function that actually provides the slider (called from theme)
 */
function simple_nivo_slider($id='slider', $category='') {

    # make sure the theme has post-thumbnail support
    if (!current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails'))
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                    jQuery('#<?php echo $id?>').nivoSlider({
                            effect: '<?php echo implode(',', get_option('snivo_nivo_effects', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_effects'))) ?>',
                            slices: <?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_slices', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_slices')) ?>,
                            boxCols: <?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_boxcols', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_boxcols')) ?>,
                            boxRows: <?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_boxrows', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_boxrows')) ?>,
                            animSpeed: <?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_animspeed', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_animspeed')) ?>,
                            pauseTime: <?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_pausetime', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_pausetime')) ?>,
                            startSlide: 0,
                            directionNav: <?php echo (get_option('snivo_nivo_directionnav', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_directionnav')) == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                            directionNavHide: <?php echo (get_option('snivo_nivo_directionnavhide', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_directionnavhide')) == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                            controlNav: <?php echo (get_option('snivo_nivo_controlnav', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_controlnav')) == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                            keyboardNav: <?php echo (get_option('snivo_nivo_keyboardnav', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_keyboardnav')) == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                            pauseOnHover: <?php echo (get_option('snivo_nivo_pauseonhover', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_pauseonhover')) == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                            captionOpacity: <?php printf("%0.1f", get_option('snivo_nivo_captionopacity', snivo_defaults('snivo_nivo_captionopacity'))/100) ?>
                    });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="<?php echo $id?>">
    <?php

    # build the post query string, then perform the query (default category is specified in plugin settings)
    $query = 'posts_per_page=-1&';
    if (empty($category))
        $query .= 'cat='.get_option('snivo_category');
    else
        $query .= 'category_name='.$category;

    # perform the query, shuffle if shuffle enabled
    if (get_option('snivo_shuffle', snivo_defaults('snivo_shuffle')))
        shuffle(query_posts($query));
    else
        query_posts($query);

    # process the results
    while (have_posts()) {

        the_post();

        if(!has_post_thumbnail())
            break;

        # determine link
        $link = trim(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'simple_nivo_link', true));
        if (empty($link))
            $link = get_permalink();

        # build 'a' opening and closing tags, if wanted
        $linkhead = $linktail = '';
        if (strtolower($link) != 'none') {
            $linkhead = "<a href=\"$link\">";
            $linktail = "</a>";
        }

        list($imgsrc) = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), get_option('snivo_imagesize', snivo_defaults('snivo_imagesize')));

        $caption = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'simple_nivo_caption', true);

        ?>
        <?php echo $linkhead ?><img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $caption ?>" /><?php echo $linktail."\n" ?>
        <?php

    }

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
        </div>
    <?php
} 


/*
 * handle snivo shortcode tags
 */
function snivo_shortcode($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 'slider',
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts));

    # place call to main plugin function using specified options
    simple_nivo_slider($id, $category);

}


/*
 * plugin administrative options page
 */
function snivo_admin_options() {

    if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))  {
        wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
    }

    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Simple Nivo Slider configuration</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php" id="simple-nivo-slider-conf">
            <?php settings_fields('snivo-settings'); ?>

            <p><table class="form-table">

            <tr><th scope="row">Post category</th><td>
            <select name="snivo_category">
                <option value="1">Select a category</option> 
            <?php 
                $category = get_option('snivo_category');
                $categories=  get_categories(); 
                foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                    $option = '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'"';
                    if ($cat->term_id == $category)
                        $option .= ' selected="selected"';
                    $option .= '>';
                    $option .= $cat->cat_name.'('.$cat->category_count.')';
                    $option .= '</option>';
                    echo $option;
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Image Size</th><td>
            <select name="snivo_imagesize">
            <?php 
                $imagesize = get_option('snivo_imagesize');
                $imagesizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
                $imagesizes[] = 'full';
                foreach (array_reverse($imagesizes) as $tmpsize) {
                    $option = '<option value="'.$tmpsize.'"';
                    if ($tmpsize == $imagesize)
                        $option .= ' selected="selected"';
                    $option .= '>';
                    $option .= $tmpsize;
                    if ($tmpsize == snivo_defaults('snivo_imagesize'))
                        $option .= ' (default)';
                    $option .= '</option>';
                    echo $option;
                }
            ?>
            </select>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Enabled effects</th><td>
            <?php
                $all_effects = explode(' ', constant('SNIVO_EFFECTS'));
                $enabled_effects = get_option('snivo_nivo_effects');
                foreach ($all_effects as $effect) {
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_effects[]" value="<?php echo $effect ?>"<?php if (in_array($effect, $enabled_effects)) echo ' checked="checked"'?>><?php echo $effect ?><br/>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Number of slices</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_slices" size="3" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_slices') ?>">
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Number of box columns</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_boxcols" size="3" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_boxcols') ?>">
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Number of box rows</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_boxrows" size="3" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_boxrows') ?>">
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Transition speed</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_animspeed" size="5" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_animspeed') ?>"> ms
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Delay between transitions</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_pausetime" size="5" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_pausetime') ?>"> ms
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Caption opacity</th><td>
            <input type="text" name="snivo_nivo_captionopacity" size="3" value="<?php echo get_option('snivo_nivo_captionopacity') ?>"> %
            </td></tr>

            <tr><th scope="row">Options</th><td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_shuffle" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_shuffle') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Shuffle image order<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_directionnav" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_nivo_directionnav') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Show directional navigation links<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_directionnavhide" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_nivo_directionnavhide') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Show directional navigation links only on hover<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_controlnav" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_nivo_controlnav') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Enable control navigation<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_keyboardnav" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_nivo_keyboardnav') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Enable keyboard navigation<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="snivo_nivo_pauseonhover" value="1"<?php if (get_option('snivo_nivo_pauseonhover') == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'?>>Pause slider on hover<br/>
            </td></tr>

            </table></p>

            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>

        </form>
        </div>
    <?php
}

/* install/uninstall */
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'snivo_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'snivo_deactivate' );
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'snivo_uninstall' );

/* actions */
add_action('admin_init', 'snivo_admin_init' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'snivo_admin_menu');

/* shortcodes */
add_shortcode('snivo', 'snivo_shortcode');

/* stylesheets */
wp_enqueue_style('nivo-slider', plugins_url('/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('simple-nivo-slider', plugins_url('/styles.css', __FILE__));

/* scripts */
wp_enqueue_script('nivo-slider', plugins_url('/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));

?>
```

Comment: You need to add more code, we aren't going to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Added the 'simple-nivo-slider.php' plug-in above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you've customized the plugin, I can only go off the code of the stock plugin.  By default, it will either use the permalink or whatever you have set in the post meta for `simple_nivo_link`.  Here's the actual code:

```
# process the results
while (have_posts()) {

    the_post();

    if(!has_post_thumbnail())
        break;

    # determine link
    $link = trim(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'simple_nivo_link', true));
    if (empty($link))
        $link = get_permalink();

    # build 'a' opening and closing tags, if wanted
    $linkhead = $linktail = '';
    if (strtolower($link) != 'none') {
        $linkhead = "<a href=\"$link\">";
        $linktail = "</a>";
    }

    list($imgsrc) = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), get_option('snivo_imagesize', snivo_defaults('snivo_imagesize')));

    $caption = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'simple_nivo_caption', true);

    ?>
    <?php echo $linkhead ?><img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>" alt="" title="<?php echo $caption ?>" /><?php echo $linktail."\n" ?>
    <?php

}
```

In English, this code loops through every post in your slider.  It calls `the_post()` to populate the regular template tag functions you know and love.  Then it checks to see if you're *manually* settings the link for the slide by putting something in the `simple_nivo_link` custom field for the post.  If you are, it uses that.  If you aren't, it uses the permalink.

However, if you have "none" set in this post meta field, the slider will omit the link entirely.

So, by default, the plugin will do exactly what you expect it to do.  If it's not outputting the permalink, then you've changed something in the code that you need to un-change.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I've only customized the CSS and have not touched the related code. In fact I just double checked the code you pasted and I have exactly that in tact, and still only the first slide links normally? Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly are the other slides linking?  Are they not outputting a link at all?  Is the `simple_nivo_link` custom field populated with any data?  From what you've told us so far, this *should* be working fine ... so there's something about your setup that's preventing it from functioning normally. If there is no link whatsoever, that means somehow that `simple_nivo_link` is being set to "none" for your other slides ...

Comment: So, it must be conflicting JS / or Plugins, right? Ughhh

Comment: That would be my guess.  Try disabling your other plugins and see if that has any effect.  Then turn them back on one-by-one to find out what's causing the issue.

Comment: Any suggestions at a manual hard-code work around? I can't seem to debug the issue?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the issue is, no. The code I'd give you to hard-code a workaround would do the exact same thing as the existing code ... so if the plugin isn't working, the workaround wouldn't work either.